# Acceptance while in Hold/Closed status

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

New answers cannot be added to a question in hold or closed status.  However, if there are existing answers at the time the question is put on hold, can one of those answers be accepted while the question is in hold or closed status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing a question will not affect if one of the existing answers is accepted, or unaccepted.

It will also not affect:

- votes
- edits
- comments